# Find both duplicates in the same ROW VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Somehow after few days of googleing I didn't find any satisfying answer.
I have to find duplicates in the same column and copy them both (or more) to the new sheet to show where are the issues.

The only way I managed to do that was

```
For i = 2 To lastCell
    If dataArray(i, 3) <> "" Then
        For j = i + 1 To lastCell
            If dataArray(i, 3) = dataArray(j, 3) Then
            results.Range("A" & k & ":" & lastCol & k).Value = checkbook.Range("A" & i & ":" & lastCol & i).Value '
            results.Range(commentAddress & k).Value = "Duplicate ID"
            k = k + 1
            results.Range("A" & k & ":" & lastCol & k).Value = checkbook.Range("A" & j & ":" & lastCol & j).Value
            results.Range(commentAddress & k).Value = "Duplicate ID"
            k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next I
```

But this is taking too long! I found that dictionary could be very helpful but don't really know how to use this - and it only shows the SECOND value (I need both)

So are there any other solutions to find duplicates? I need the fastest one as the file I am working on has 100K+ rows (loop in a loop is killing me)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something similar to this to recreate the column with blanks replacing the duplicate values. Then you can just filter on blank values in the column to find which values or IDs are duplicates. Or write a formula that loops through column and collects addresses of cells that are empty.

```
=IF(A1="";"";IF(COUNTIF(A1:A100;A1)=1;A1;""))
```

Replace A1:A100 with the range your data occupy, or the whole column if you prefere.